# Apache Camel web console's scalate servlet fails in WebLogic

Tags: java, scala, weblogic, apache-camel, scalate

I've found a similar issue described in detail in the [scala mailing list](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/scala-recent-changes-in-2-8-nightly-classpath-management-td2004171.html) (also [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/5152)). It seems to be related to [this](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/changeset/19285/scala/trunk/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/Settings.scala) change in classpath management when creating scala interpretation environments.

In my case both `scala-library` and `scala-compiler` are included in the `war` being deployed to **WebLogic 10.3** (camel version: 2.8.0, jvm: oracle 1.6).

The exception is shown below:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateException: object scala not found.
    at org.fusesource.scalate.jersey.ScalateTemplateProcessor.writeToUsingServletTemplateEngine(ScalateTemplateProcessor.scala:190)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.jersey.ScalateTemplateProcessor.writeTo(ScalateTemplateProcessor.scala:136)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.jersey.ScalateTemplateProcessor.writeTo(ScalateTemplateProcessor.scala:44)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.template.ResolvedViewable.writeTo(ResolvedViewable.java:103)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter.writeTo(ViewableMessageBodyWriter.java:83)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateException: object scala not found.
    at org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.compileAndLoad(TemplateEngine.scala:784)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.compileAndLoadEntry(TemplateEngine.scala:643)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.liftedTree1$1(TemplateEngine.scala:374)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.load(TemplateEngine.scala:368)
    at org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.load(TemplateEngine.scala:426)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: scala.tools.nsc.MissingRequirementError: object scala not found.
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.getModuleOrClass(Definitions.scala:653)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.getModule(Definitions.scala:603)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.ScalaPackage(Definitions.scala:145)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.ScalaPackageClass(Definitions.scala:146)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.AnyClass(Definitions.scala:176)
```

The question: is it possible to make camel web-console work in this environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No its a problem with WebLogic. Scalaete needs to add special support for WebLogic, as WebLogic does classloading a bit differently, than the usual practice.

Comment: That's a shame. Maybe you've already got pointers to what should be fixed in **scalate**?

Comment: Its somewhere in the TemplateEngine, when loading the pre compiled classes: https://github.com/scalate/scalate/blob/master/scalate-core/src/main/scala/org/fusesource/scalate/TemplateEngine.scala